# A bot that says user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So basically, I'm trying to get my code to make my bot see that when a user types 't!say #channel "message"' in any text channel, the bot will go to the specified channel and say "message"

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
 name: 'say',
 aliases: ['bc', 'broadcast'],
 description: 'Says your input via the bot',
 usage: '<input>',
 run: async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_MESSAGES'])) {
   if (message.mentions.channels.size == 0) {
    message.reply('please mention a channel first.');
   } else if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_MESSAGES'])) {
    let targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
    // Get the message to print

    const args = message.content.split(' ').slice(2);
    let saytext = args.join(' ');
    targetChannel.send(saytext);
    message.delete();
   }
  }
 },
};
```

When I try to use the command, I get an error in the console that says "TypeError: client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function"

and here is the code snippet from my index.js file that the command prompt says its located at

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

 const args = message.content
  .slice(prefix.length)
  .trim()
  .split(/ +/);
 const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

 try {
  client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
 } catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
 }
});
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The error you've posted says the problem is with `client.commands.get().execute` however in the snippet of code you've posted, that line isn't present. Please update your question to show the related piece of code where the error occurs else we can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question my guess would be that the error is caused by you calling `.execute()` on the command whilst a command does not have an `execute` function. From your `say` command code, it looks like your commands have a `.run` function.

So try changing

```js
client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
```

to

```js
// I've added the `client` property because your run command takes three arguments, not two.
client.commands.get(command).run(client, message, args);
```

Comment: When I tried that, it caused every other command to throw the error "TypeError: client.commands.get(...).run is not a function" and the say command wouldn't output anything.

Comment: So for every other command you have an `execute` function instead? Why did you create a Say command file with a `run` command? Anyways, to fix that issue you'd have to change the `run:` to `execute:` in the Say command and revert the changes you made based on my answer

Comment: And as for why your Say command wouldn't output anything, the first line in the execute function checks if the user does NOT have the `MANAGE_MESSAGES` permission, and if so, executes the command. So a user who does have said permission, won't execute the command. My guess is that you meant to check if the user has the permission, not if they did not have that